# Changing case of SMTP in Exchange 2007

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I have a client that wishes to change their case. Currently their domain (changed for privacy) is named Tom Allen Jones, CPA with a Windows AD domain tajonescpa.com and for some reason he'd like to have the SMTP addresses show as "TAJonesCPA.com" as the reply to address.

Inside of Exchange Management Console, I created a test user and used the old way (testuser@tajones.com) and then changed the SMTP address to TestUser@TAJonesCPA.com but only the user's portion of the email address was changed, the domain name remained in all lower case. I also modified the AD object without any change.

Is there some way to modify this without going into a ton of hassle? It's only for about a dozen users so its not like I'd spend all day manually modifying attributes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new e-mail adress policy. [here is an Exchange Server 2010 – Email Address Policy – How-To](http://www.myexchangeworld.com/2010/07/exchange-server-2010-email-address-policy-how-to/) that both show you how to do it using the MMC and the PowerShell command line.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit of a kludge, but you could temporarily change the address to X-testuser@TAJonesCPA.com. Then save the change. Wait a minute and remove the "X-" from the beginning of the address. So the final address is testuser@TAJonesCPA.com. Sometimes you have to fully change the address to some other value for the UPPER/lower case change to be recognized.

Of course, you would want to be quick so new messages for the recipient don't bounce.